# "Badger someone"

Tags: etymology, american-english, british-english, word-usage

I've heard the expression "to badger someone" in British English usage, and not being able to find out about its origins, I wonder if it is also commonly used elsewhere, for example, in American English?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=badger+someone&searchmode=none

Comment: http://www.badgerbadgerbadger.com/

Comment: Must be common in the US, too - there is a Penguins of Madagascar episode focused completely on the term...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary gives for "badger, v(erb). 2":

> *trans*. To bait, hound; to subject to persistent harassment or persecution; to pester, bother; (in later use freq.) to ply with repeated and irritating requests to do something.

with examples from 1782.

It doesn't mark it as characteristic of any particular variety of English. I don't know whether it is used outside the UK.

Comment: I live in the US northeast, and we use it here.

Comment: It's common throughout the US.  One common occurance is on courtroom TV shows when an attorney is accused of "badgering the witness".

Answer (score 0):

If anything, to "badger" someone is more common in America, and American English, than in British English.

"Badgers" are small, furry, carnivores native to the northern U.S. As such, they can be highly annoying, though ultimately not dangerous (to humans).

Therefore to "badger" someone is to "annoy" or "harass" someone, without actually harming them.

Comment: My impression is that badgers are much more common in England than they are in the U.S. (although they are native to both places). [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=badger) says the verb *badger* is derived from the way dogs were used in badger hunting, which is a British, and not American, sport of previous centuries.

Comment: But the OED (which has examples going back 12 years further than etymonline) says " < badger n.2, probably with allusion to baiting or drawing of badgers by humans, although compare also 17th-cent. allusions to the supposed tenacity of a badger in biting until its teeth met "

Comment: Anyway, checking Google Books shows that all the confirmed uses of *badgering* or *badgered* they come up with before 1800 (these were all in the 1790s) were British. The word seems not to have changed in meaning since then.